# &#39; and everything after that is not being sent by the browser

Tags: http, browser, proxy

I have a proxy server setup for my browser (Firefox 21, IE10). The strange thing is whenever there is & # 3 9 ; (please ignore the spaces) in the request URL, the browser will not sent it and anything after that.

Initially I thought this is a problem with the proxy server, so I wrote a simple socket server and try to see what the browser sends (see below). When I debug through the code the it proves that the browser indeed is NOT sending ' and everything after that. Anyone has ever seen this before? Why is this happening?

```
    nFd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(nFd < 0) break;

    sockaddr_in addr = {0};
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    addr.sin_port = htons(7995);
    int nAddrLen = sizeof(addr);

    if(0 != ::bind(nFd, (const sockaddr*)&addr, nAddrLen))
        break;

    if(0 != listen(nFd, 64))
        break;

    nClientFd = accept(nFd, (sockaddr*)&addr, &nAddrLen);
    if(nClientFd < 0) break;


    char buf[16384] = {0};
    int nBytesRead = recv(nClientFd, buf, 16384, 0);
    if(nBytesRead <= 0) break;

    cout << buf << endl;
```

Here is the request that I type to the address bar (ignore the spaces in & # 3 9 ;, it's only there so that it will show up on this page:

> www.test.com/go& # 3 9 ; tome

Here is the request that I received through the socket:

**GET http://www.test.com/go& HTTP/1.1** 
Host: www.test.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

Note the request line. I really cannot explain this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#` character is reserved in HTTP/HTTPS URLs and marks the beginning of the URL's `fragment` component. This part of a HTTP/HTTPS URL is never sent to the server. If you want the # character and subsequent information to be sent to the server, the # must be URLEncoded to %23.